# Thermodynamic Properties

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose a certain quantity of gas is taken in a closed container and then the mass of the gas is doubled keeping the volume and temperature constant. So the pressure of the gas now doubles too. Isn't pressure now behaving like an extensive property since it's depending upon the amount of matter present?

Comment: Extensive doesn't mean "depends on the amount of matter".

Answer (score 2):

No, because you have changed the system that you are analysing, by adding more mass. For a quantity to be extensive , it would mean that if you take half of your system ,(Half the volume and half the mass) the property remains the same (Pressure)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a pure system for simplicity. The four parameters pressure, volume, temperature, and moles $p, V, T, n$ completely specify the state of the system. A mechanical equation of state always exists to relate the four parameters, so only three are fully independent.

State that the system is *CLOSED*. This means, you specify the mass (moles) of the system as a constant. Only two of the four starting parameters remain entirely independent and free to vary. For the starting closed system, you may choose its total mass (moles) and one (and only one) of these three sets of parameters: $(p, T)$, $(p, V)$, or $(T, V)$.

At this point, you may ask whether this means that pressure, temperature, and volume are extensive properties. Let's do a few thought experiments.

Suppose that you want to compare your system with another that has more mass. You can choose to do so in one of three different universes. In our universe, we do the comparison at the same $(p, T)$. We find that the system with the larger volume has the larger mass. Indeed, a definition of a substance in our universe is anything that has mass *and takes up space* (has volume). The direct association between volume and mass becomes an intuitive if not fundamental, first-principles definition of volume as an extensive property.

Alternatively, you can propose to do the comparison of your two systems in a universe where their $(V, T)$ values must be exactly the same. In that universe (which is NOT our universe), you will find that pressure $p$ depends on mass. In that universe, you can define pressure as an extensive variable. That definition cannot carry over to our universe because the two parameters of comparison are not the same sets.

In some cases for the analysis of thermodynamics of systems, temperature and pressure are classed as field variables while mass is combined with volume explicitly and classed as a density variable. In essence, we do not talk about "temperature density" or "pressure density" when we analyze systems in our universe, we talk about temperature, pressure, and (mass, molar, or number) density.

In summary, while pressure depends on mass in a case of constant $(V, T)$, that is not the requirement to make pressure an extensive variable. The requirement of the definition of extensive is made foremost in our universe of constant $(p, T)$.